# Avoid Failed to read from defunct connection when using neo4j in Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, bolt

I am using the following version of neo4j libraries:

```
neo4j==1.7.2
neobolt==1.7.9
neotime==1.7.4
```

I have a flask app and in development I am using the internal flask application server. (In prod I will use a docker container with uwsgi, but this quesiton is about my dev setup.)

I have encapsuated neo4j into a class and my application maintains a single instance of this class:

```
class ChartStoreConnectionClass():
  driver = None

  def __init__(self, configDict):
    self.driver = neo4j.GraphDatabase.driver(
      configDict["boltUri"],
      auth=(configDict["basicAuthUsername"], configDict["basicAuthPassword"]),
      encrypted=True,
      trust=neo4j.TRUST_SYSTEM_CA_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES,
      # trust=neo4j.TRUST_ALL_CERTIFICATES,
      # trust=neo4j.TRUST_CUSTOM_CA_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES, Custom CA support is not implemented
    )

  def readonlyQuery(self, queryFN):
    res = None
    with self.driver.session() as session:
      tx = session.begin_transaction()
      res = queryFN(tx)
      tx.rollback()
    return res

  def execute(self, queryFN):
    res = None
    with self.driver.session() as session:
      tx = session.begin_transaction()
      res = queryFN(tx)
      tx.commit()
    return res
```

This setup works for a while, but sometimes I get the following error:

```
neobolt.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Failed to read from defunct connection Address(host='127.0.0.1',
port=7687)
```

when I simply retry the request it works the second time. I have read around the error message and found mutiple posts talking about neo4j in multi-threaded vs multi-process environments but I do not believe they are relevant to me here.

There errors are occurring on the commit of the execute function. The queryFN I pass to it is a very simple one liner which takes next to no time to execute.

Is it wrong to have a single driver instance for my application? (I thought this was the way to do it because the driver creates a connection pool and it makes sense that my application has a connection pool.)

What is the recommended way to use neo4j with Flask? 
I have seen this example https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-python-bolt/blob/master/movies.py but they simply have a single driver object in the same way as I do. (Except that is global not inside a class, but functionally mine is the same.)

Where should I be looking to debug this issue?

Comment: I got this error working with docker version of the neo4j in windows and solved it by passing some environment value in docker run command https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-run-neo4j/

Comment: Which variable resolved the error?

Comment: -e NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_advertised__address="localhost:7473" -e NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address="localhost:7474" -e NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address="localhost:7687"